# How to generate scriptPubKey?

Tags: public-key, address-generation

My address is 389CLh5Ect2i7U5116gqjBSLykYHRmdcgZ. In request from site i see this
scriptPubKey, how i can generate this scriptPubKey from my Address
{scriptPubKey: "a91446c443cc449d9e9a54a9e07a30dfd2ab1960a18f87", value: 60000} ?

If you have examples in javascript it will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the partial answer, on the underlying logic. I cannot help with java script. The critical part would be the base58decoding, but it seems there are solutions already: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base58check

**Underlying logic:**

the scriptpubkey contains the RipeMD160 Hash, surrounded by some codes:
a9 14  87. This is a P2SH address.

the meaning of the codes is:

```
a9 -> do a RipeMD160 on the top stack item
14 -> push hex 14 (decimal 20) bytes on stack
87 -> check if the top two stack elements are equal
```

From your address, you need four steps, to come to this goal:

```
1.) base58decode the address
2.) remove last 4 bytes (this is a checksum)
3.) remove the first two bytes (the network prefix
4.) surround the codes to it
```

effectivly the procedure is the revers of the standard "base58check encoding": which answers, how to come from a pubkey in hexformat to
 an address:

```
0: have a Private ECDSA Key
1: derive the Public ECDSA Key
2: do a SHA-256 of 1
3: RIPEMD-160 Hash of 2
4: add address prefix 0x00 for P2PKH, 0x05 for P2SH
5. sha256
6. another sha256
7. take first four Bytes from step 6 as checksum
8. append checksum from step 7 to the result from step4
9. encode Base58
```

--> your bitcoin address !

help while testing: http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address
(hint: never put your production private keys into a webpage - you might/will loose the funds on it!)

Comment: scriptPubKey is static or dynamic ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by static or dynamic. The pubkey is derived from the private key via the ECDSA logic, then hashed, concatenated with a prefix and chcksummed, re-assembled and bas58encoded. There are other pubkey-scripts, which can be assembled dynamically, but not keys...